# Create new spreadsheet in Google Drive Picker

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive Picker frontend library for showing spreadsheets. One problem is that I would like the user to also be able to create a new spreadsheet directly from the Picker, instead of having to go to Google Drive, create a spreadsheet and select it. Is this possible? The scope I'm using is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you can't use or modify the view from the Drive Picker API to create files but only to visualize and select them. In order to create files you need the Drive API `files.create` method.

Depending on your particular use case this could even be better for the user experience because with the `files.create` method you already obtain a file instance upon the file creation for any particular use within your app, therefore you would be saving the step of having to manually search for the file within Drive using the view from the Drive Picker API and the select it.

What I would do is to have 2 buttons:

1. To search for existing files using the Drive Picker API.
2. To create a new file and immediately start working with that file by reading the file instance I get from creating it.

As an additional suggestion, I think it would be easier to have the option to create files within the Drive Picker API. You can submit a feature request in Google's issue tracker so that they may consider adding this in the near future (see link below).

#### References:

- [Method: files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create)
- [Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)